# Login failed for 'SA' SQL Server Authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api2, connection-string

I am getting Login Failed for 'SA'. I am creating a WebAPI and myconnection string contains User Id and Password.

Some More Details :

- I have enabled mix mode in SQl Sever.
- I am able to Login in SSMS through the Same Credintials.

What i have observed So Far :

- The Error Arise only when i am browsing through IIS, debugging with Visual Studio works fine.
- Also, adding Integrated Security=True solves the issue.
- And the Error arises only if i am pointing physical path to the published folder.
- If i point physical path to source code then also it works fine.

I have tried the above things and came to know that exception is thrown only if :

- Physical Path is set to Publish Folder along with Sql Server Authentication.

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't be using the `SA` account to connect applications to your database, as you're giving the application administrative level powers on your database. You should be using a specific account, just for the application, that has restricted permissions to only be able to do what is required for the application and nothing more.

Comment: I will make sure to create account but for now i am stuck with this.

Comment: `Also, adding Integrated Security=True solves the issue. ` You are using `sa` account - integrated security must be ON in order to grant you access to db.

Comment: But i am providing Password for `sa` Account

Comment: @Steve if you want to use `sa` or any other SQL Sever user - you must use `Integrated Security=True`. If you want to login via domain account - you should turn it off `Integrated Security=False`

Comment: @gofr1 if i use `Integrated Security = True` then SQL Server will use Windows Authentication right?? But i want to use SQL Authentication!

Comment: @Steve no *integrated* means internal security. if it is turned off - then it will use external (like domain auth).

Comment: @gofr1 if i host site to then ?

Comment: @Steve And what should that mean? :) There are few possibilities for your site to work with SQL Server. F.e. I run IIS on my machine, and I use windows auth for users to work with DB. And I got another web service, that uses 1 internal login to share some report with *no matter who* is connected. It depends on what you need.